# Can you disable web exceptions?

Tags: vb.net, exception, web, http-status-code-404

I was wondering if you could disable Web Exceptions, for example,

> 404 Not Found

Comment: Why Are You Typing Like This?

Comment: @simchona: Some People Think They'll Get More Attention If They Type In Marketeer Caps.  And Apparently, Some People In India Were Just Taught English By People With a Caps Fetish.

Comment: Anyway, why can't you just catch the exception and handle it?  (Note, i said *handle* it, not just sweep it under the rug. :) )

Comment: Can you exlplain how i would do that?

EDIT: Ive tried wraping it in a try and catch but no luck :/

Comment: How is this different from the other two times you asked the same question? Why should this not be closed as another duplicate?

Comment: This is my second question lol

Comment: It's the same as the first two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't disable WebExceptions.  Like most other exceptions, their whole point is to signal a problem that's not fixable at the point where it happened.  You can't just ignore that and expect your app to work.

What you do is *catch and handle* the exception.  Like so.

```
Try
    Dim response = request.GetResponse()

    '... do stuff with response here ...

Catch ex as WebException
    ' Note, `response` probably isn't usable here!  Pretty sure it's
    ' out of scope.  In any case, if `GetResponse` is throwing the
    ' exception, then it didn't return a value.  However, you should be
    ' able to access `ex.Response` to get info about the response,
    ' including the HTTP response code.
    Dim errorResponse = CType(ex.Response, HttpWebResponse)
    If errorResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound Then

        '... handle error ...

    Else
        ' if it's not a 404, we're not doing anything about the exception
        ' so rethrow it
        Throw
    End If
End Try

' Note, `response` is out of scope here!
```

Answer (score -1):

This has to be done in IIS.

To do this navigate to Start -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> IIS

Select your web server in the list and double click the Error Pages options

Add a specific web page for the error message that you are trying to replace or remove.

Here is a great walk through in case you need more detail: http://www.braintrove.com/id/46

Comment: You can't disable an exception from happening.  If your website has a missing page it has a missing page, no way around it.  What you can do is handle/prevent the exception properly, which is what I demonstrated.

Comment: No, you didn't. Changing the error page has nothing to do with handling the exception.

Comment: I'm curious as to how you would put a Try Catch block around a 404 exception.  If your web server is throwing a page not found most likely you are not in page code.  By redirecting your exception you can force it to a page for handling that specific error.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10175966/76337. Also, redirecting to an error page does not constitute _handling_ the exception.